# Fast way of Identifying Larger amounts of OverlapCircle Sensor Data

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm still a beginner and haven't got much experience in performance optimization and so on and i have the following scenario in a little simulation attempt.

Agents have 3 overlapCircle sensors which each scan 2-3 different layers which in some cases contain multiple entities, further categorized via multiple tags each (Food,Agent Type, Faction, etc.).
Im already filtering my LayerMasks depending on the state of the agent but then still have to decide which colliders (could be up to about 50-100 colliders at a time) i count and care about, depending on the tags of the gameObjects.

The sensors are already running in a coroutine at 500ms to save time (quicker would be better) but i'm sure with all the loops through nested dictionaries i'm going to run into issues quickly with more than a hundred or so agents.

As an example, im looping through this kind of collection multiple times for detection and processing and it makes me uncomfortable already and wonder if that is sustainable -_- :

```
//That would be: SensorID, Layer and the Colliders....
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<Collider2D>>> processedData;
```

- I'm guessing so many colliders aren't a good thing to begin with? But is there another way?
- Should i pre-filter with more different Layers? In my brain, interactive agents are all on the same layer, no matter what faction or whatever..
- Is there a better way to categorize entities than my multiple tags custom script, since this still requires a GetComponent call in a loop -_-
- Should i have the whole code to process the sensor data in a coroutine instead of update?
- Or is there nothing to worry about unless i do that with tens of thousands of Agents?

No need for code but I would be grateful for some input on what would be fast and proper ways of doing these things.

Thanks ;)

No need for code but I would be grateful for some input on what would be fast and proper ways of doing these things.

Thanks ;)

Comment: " is there nothing to worry about " - A general rule is to measure first, worry later. In the simplest case, just add a stopwatch around some code , and print the time to console or check it in the debugger. This will not be accurate in debug builds, but it should give a decent upper bound on the time.

Comment: Ok, so does that mean you don't see anything in my approach that immediately triggers a "omg, that's no way to do that" or just "do it however you like as long as it runs"? ;)
I did check with the profiler and already had regular spikes but apparently coming from the Editor loop..
You're right, maybe i should wait for issues first but i'm asking here early because i'm still working on/finishing the sensor system and the more code i write, the more i'm wondering if this is not way too much for what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm not proficient in unity, so I would not be able to tell. The typical solution of finding nearby objects would be to use some kind of spatial tree, like a kd-tree or octree. I would expect unity to do this internally, but I have no idea of actual runtimes or things that should be avoided.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.